# Filling a 3D Matrix by for loops with values in R

Tags: r, 3d, for-loop, matrix

I set up a 3 dimensinoal matrix of size 365x7x4.

```
x <- array(rep(1, 365*5*4), dim=c(365, 5, 4))
```

Now I would to use a for loop to fill each element with a value.
Lets say the value of each element should be sum of row, column and depth.
I guess this is relatively easy.

Thanks! best, F

Comment: It is an array! Also the array is already filled, so do you mean to take the current `x` and then replace all the elements? By "depth" do you mean the third dimension? It would help if you gave a simpler (smaller) example with expected output so we know exactly what you want. If we sum over the 3 dimensions we'd have far fewer unique values. Also, there will be no need for a loop; try to think vectorised with R.

Comment: you're right, I want to assign a specified value to each element. depth=3rd dimension... Example: The element [3,4,5] <- should be filled with 3+4+5. This should be done for each element [x,y,z] by x+y+z.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a simpler example so we can see what is being done

```
arr <- array(seq_len(3*3*3), dim = rep(3,3,3))
```

the following code gives the requested output:

```
dims <- dim(arr)
ind <- expand.grid(lapply(dims, seq_len))
arr[] <- rowSums(ind)
```

The above gives

```
> arr
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    5
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    5    6    7

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]    5    6    7
[3,]    6    7    8

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    6    7
[2,]    6    7    8
[3,]    7    8    9

> arr[1,1,1]
[1] 3
> arr[1,2,3]
[1] 6
> arr[3,3,3]
[1] 9
```

**Update:** Using the example in @TimP's Answer here I update the Answer to show how it can be done in a more R-like fashion.

Given

```
arr <- array(seq_len(3*3*3), dim = rep(3,3,3))
```

Replace elements of `arr` with `i + j + k` unless `k > 2`, in which case `j*k-i` is used instead.

```
dims <- dim(arr)
ind <- expand.grid(lapply(dims, seq_len))
## which k > 2
want <- ind[,3] > 2
arr[!want] <- rowSums(ind[!want, ])
arr[want] <- ind[want, 2] * ind[want, 3] - ind[want, 1]
```

Whilst it is tempting to stick with familiar idioms like looping, and contrary to popular belief loops are *not* inefficient in R, learning to think in a vectorised way will pay off many times over as you learn the language and start applying it to data analysis task.

Here are some timings on Fabian's example:

```
> x <- array(rep(1, 365*5*4), dim=c(365, 5, 4))
> system.time({
+ for (i in seq_len(dim(x)[1])) {
+     for (j in seq_len(dim(x)[2])) {
+         for (k in seq_len(dim(x)[3])) {
+             val = i+j+k
+             if (k > 2) {
+                 val = j*k-i
+             }
+             x[i,j,k] = val
+         }
+     }
+ }
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.043   0.000   0.044 
> arr <- array(rep(1, 365*5*4), dim=c(365, 5, 4))
> system.time({
+ dims <- dim(arr)
+ ind <- expand.grid(lapply(dims, seq_len))
+ ## which k > 2
+ want <- ind[,3] > 2
+ arr[!want] <- rowSums(ind[!want, ])
+ arr[want] <- ind[want, 2] * ind[want, 3] - ind[want, 1]
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.005   0.000   0.006
```

and for a much larger (for my ickle laptop at least!) problem

```
> x <- array(rep(1, 200*200*200), dim=c(200, 200, 200))
> system.time({
+ for (i in seq_len(dim(x)[1])) {
+     for (j in seq_len(dim(x)[2])) {
+         for (k in seq_len(dim(x)[3])) {
+             val = i+j+k
+             if (k > 2) {
+                 val = j*k-i
+             }
+             x[i,j,k] = val
+         }
+     }
+ }
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
 51.759   0.129  53.090
> arr <- array(rep(1, 200*200*200), dim=c(200, 200, 200))
> system.time({
+     dims <- dim(arr)
+     ind <- expand.grid(lapply(dims, seq_len))
+     ## which k > 2
+     want <- ind[,3] > 2
+     arr[!want] <- rowSums(ind[!want, ])
+     arr[want] <- ind[want, 2] * ind[want, 3] - ind[want, 1]
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  2.282   1.036   3.397
```

but even that may be modest to small by today's standards. You can see that the looping starts to become ever more uncompetitive because of the all the function calls required by that method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! The example with the sums should only be an easy example how for loops in 3d arrasy work. I would like to use more complex operations. E.g. in the object [i,j,k] assign "a" if i < 3, multiply j*k if k>1 and substract i from it.

Comment: This may (or may not) help, but the nth element of a 3d array indexed by `[i,j,k]` is given by `((k-1) * (nr*nc)) + ((j-1) * nc) + i` where `nr` & `nc` are the numbers of rows an columns respectively. Given that, you can assign any value you want subject to whatever condition you want by `myArray[foo] <- value` where `foo` is the index returned by snippet above. That snippet is vectorised; for vectors of values for each of `i`, `j` & `k` it will return a vector of indices of the elements of the array. If you create the replacement vector, these two combined mean you don't need loops.

Comment: +1 Gavin for managing to get four of my favourite functions into two lines of code :)

Answer (score 3):

Fabian: from the phrasing of your question, I believe you're just looking for a simple way of setting values in the array to follow any set of rules you might devise. No problem.

Your array is small (and from the context I strongly suspect you only want to use the code for something of that size). So good practice is simply to use a set of three `for` loops, which will run almost instantly - no need for any unnecessary complications. My code below shows an example: here we set element `x[i,j,k]` to be `i+j+k`, unless `k>2`, in which case we set it to be `j*k-i` instead.

Obviously, you can have as many rules as you want - just add an `if` statement for each one, and define `val` to be the value you want `x[i,j,k]` to take if that condition is true. (There's a few different ways to set this up, but this one seems the simplest to understand.) At the end of the innermost loop, `x[i,j,k]` gets set to the required value (`val`), and we then go on and do the next element until they're all done. That's it!

```
x = array(rep(1, 365*5*4), dim=c(365, 5, 4))

for (i in seq_len(dim(x)[1])) {
    for (j in seq_len(dim(x)[2])) {
        for (k in seq_len(dim(x)[3])) {
            val = i+j+k
            if (k > 2) {
                val = j*k-i
            }
            x[i,j,k] = val
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

**Quick update (non-loopy method):** For completeness, if you're in a real hurry and want your code to run in 0.07 seconds rather than 0.19 seconds... you could also set things up in a vectory way like this:

```
comb = expand.grid(seq_len(365), seq_len(5), seq_len(4))
i = comb$Var1; j = comb$Var2; k = comb$Var3
val = i+j+k
subs = which(k>2); val[subs] = (j*k-i)[subs]
x = array(val, dim = c(365, 5, 4))
```

In the above, the variables `i`, `j` and `k` are vectors with length 7300 (the number of cells in the array). As before, the default choice for `val` is the sum `i+j+k` except on the subset `k>2`, where `val` is `j*k-i` instead - exactly the same as the example in the first part of my answer. Obviously the notation in this method is quite a bit harder which is why I thought it'd be better to show you the loop-based solution. Hopefully you'll see how you could add in other conditions to the above though. The final line maps the vector `val` over to the array `x` in the right way so that each `x[i,j,k]` takes on the correct value of `val`. Try it and see :)

One small point to note though: if you were ever to want to run this sort of algorithm on a massive array (much, much, much bigger than the one you have now), then the approach immediately above would definitely be the one to use to minimise runtime. For your case, my advice is to use whichever one you feel more comfortable with as the runtime isn't really an issue.

Cheers! :)

Comment: this is very inefficient because of the the large number of calls to `"[()"`, use of scalar computations which R is inefficient at, and the evaluations of the `if()`. It is far better to do this in a single `"[()"` call by preparing the replacement vector ahead of time using vectorised operations, not one at a time as shown here. This might be quick enough for the current problem, but doesn't represent the way R should be used. If you learn this and then apply to a bigger problem the inefficiencies will start to show.

Comment: Come on, Gavin! It's abundantly clear in my answer that I'm only advocating this method because the OP's problem is so small. Life's too short - let's solve the problem that needs solving, and write the code in a way that's totally clear to the guy asking the question (so he can adapt it). The code ran on my machine in 0.19 secs, less than 1% of the time it took to write this comment. It's foolish to optimise something that doesn't need optimising... isn't it?

Comment: I +1'd your post as it is better than my attempts in the comments to convey what the OP might have wanted. It is not "good" R, but it works. I have no problem with that, but it is important to point out the deficiencies with this approach in general - not this specific example. A lot of things will become much easier if one forgets the loop idiom and works with R rather than against it.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, if you have chance I'd be grateful if you could take a look at my non-loopy stab and see if you have any suggestions to improve it? Want to try and keep the notation as simple as poss, obviously :)

Comment: Yep, that looks right and very similar to the version I just updated my Answer with. You could improve it by not doing the `i+j+k` operation for the cases where we don't need it, but unless the number of elements is truly massive it will make little difference. Also, if you name the elements in `expand.grid(i = seq_len(365), ....)` then you can skip the next line you show pulling each out into `i`, `j` etc, and then use `comb[, "i"]` etc, which maintains link to the `i`, etc but doesn't incur further copies of what might be large objects.

Comment: Yep, agree with all your points. I'd normally refer directly to the values in `comb` but wanted to keep the notation as simple as poss for the OP... and unless `comb` is gargantuan, making copies probably won't be an issue. I guess with all these questions / answers, it really depends whether you're seeking code optimality, simplicity, or a compromise between the two :)