# Saving output from for-loop to 3D array in R

Tags: r, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am working in R to save outputs from a 'for' loop in to a 3D matrix. I have been unable to adapt a similar example answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967596/filling-a-3d-matrix-by-for-loops-with-values-in-r) for my purposes, so I'd like to share a different example.

I have a mostly-completed "for" loop that generates slopes and intercepts from a linear model for N iterations; with each iteration using a new set of y-values with a random t-distribution ('rt').

The desired resulting output is a 3D matrix with two slices, here named "out2". One slice is named "Intercept" and the other is "Slope."  Each column in both of the sheets is a result from the model generated with different degrees of dreedom (dfs)

```
set.seed(14)
x <- sample(0:50, 15)    # Generate x-values for simulation

true.a <- 1.5      # Intercept for linear relationship
true.m <- 5        # Slope for linear relationship
dfs <- c(1,2,3,4,6,8,10,15,20,25)   # Degrees of freedom
N <- 1000          # Reps in for-loop

out2 <- array(NA, dim=c(N, length(dfs), 2))
dimnames(out2) <- list(NULL, dfs, c("Intercept", "Slope"))

for(j in 1:length(dfs)) {

df.tdist <- dfs[j]

for(i in 1:N)  {
   y <- true.a + true.m * x + 25*rt(15,df.tdist)
   fit <- lm(y ~ x)
   out2[ ] <- ?????????????

 # The output array 'out2' will consist of two "slices", one with intercepts
     and one with slopes.  The length of each slice is 1000 rows, and the 
  width of each slice is 10 columns

 }
}
```

Thanks greatly in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Where do `true.a`, `true.b` and `x` come from?

Comment: I've edited the code to include assignments for "x", "true.a", and "true.b".  I accidentally neglected to include them in my original copy/paste of the code!

Comment: if all we want is `fit$slope` and `fit$intercept`, what is the purpose of the `CI <- confint(fit)`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `out2[i,j,1] <- y` and `out2[i,j,2] <- CI`

Comment: how would that store the 2x2 matrix object resulting from `confint`?

Comment: The line that creates confidence intervals was for a different purpose unrelated to this question.  For now, it is OK if that output is not saved.  I've removed it from the above code.